# php saving object in session

Tags: php, session, serialization

I'm trying to save an object in `$_SESSION`, but the following:

```
<?php

$user = db->load( $username, $pass ) ;
$_SESSION[ 'user' ] = $user ;

# on subsequent page loads:
$user = $_SESSION[ 'user' ] ; #retrieve the user from session
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

> The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "User" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

Unless you use serialize():

```
<?php

$user = db->load( $username, $pass ) ;
$_SESSION[ 'user' ] = serialize( $user ) ;

# on subsequent page loads:
$user = unserialize( $_SESSION[ 'user' ] ) ; #retrieve the user from session
```

I'm assuming a serialize is required because Session info is saved out to disk.  But shouldn't PHP be smart enough to serialize stuff on its own?

And with the use of **serialize**/_*unserialize*_, is this going to work now reliably?  Or do I need a `__serialize()` method in my PHP class?

Comment: Have you ever think about use Zend.Session?

Answer (score 4):

You would need the `__serialize()` in your class if your object needs to perform some action before being serialized. For instance if it had a reference to an open file and that file needed to be properly closed before serializing.

Comment: In this case you would use __sleep and __wakeup < http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php >

Comment: My apologies, that is what I meant, there is no php magic method called __serialize().

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe use [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)? I only just learned about it today, so maybe it's not really that relevant.

Comment: `var_export()` isn't really a serialization function. It's just to create a human-readable string representation of a variable (like `var_dump()`. It doesn't create a full representation of the variable, and there's no reverse function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: @Lèse My understanding of `var_export` was that the string it returns could be `eval` ed to get (more or less) the same variable. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I had it confused with `print_r()`. However, it's still better to serialize objects with `serialize()` as there are some cases where the output of `var_export()` will not produce the proper results (e.g. objects with circular references).

Comment: Yeah but, is this an efficient choice?

Comment: It depends; I think it can be if you don't need to serialize objects that `var_export` isn't compatible with. I personally try to avoid `eval`, but it's a valid way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the php compiler is concerned all you are doing is writing an object (serialised) to an Array its a different process that ensures $_SESSION is available on the next page.  Serialisation is nothing to do with being written to disk more to do with memory as the memory allocated to various methods on your object will not be available on the next page.  Serialisation is how PHP holds onto objects accross pages, and you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Better Use

```
json_encode()  json_decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach this days is to implement [Serializable](https://www.php.net/serializable) interface with your class.